# Can we upload Zip file in sharepoint 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, zip

Hey  i wanted to ask can we upload zip file to SharePoint 2013.

I am working on sharepoint 2013 .I want to make a site content in which user can click on zip file and it will ask for (do you want to download it  yes/no)
and get saved in  my PC.

I have no access to central adminstrator.I just wanted to make it ease for some one who can access the url and simply click on zip file to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can upload Zip files in SharePoint.